# Does data arriving to the topic of GlobalKTable trigger join?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have two topics with the following data:

```
<ClientId, ClientConfiguration> configurationTopic;
<ClientId, User> userTopic;
```

ClientId is just a UUID string here.

The configurationTopic is fairly small, and can be compacted because we only care about the most recent configuration for any client.

The userTopic is going to be much larger. I don't see how I can have it partition by clientId, because the system would never scale. A client with a larger number of users would have significantly worse performance, because all messages would have to be read by a single consumer.

What I need to happen is anytime we get an updated User (created, updated, deleted) I want to re-process that user with the latest ClientConfiguration. If the ClientConfiguration gets updated I need to re-process that configuration for each User. I do realize that this might re-process a lot of data, but it should be fine as long as the work can be spread across multiple consumers.

I was looking into turning the ConfigurationTopic into a global KTable, which would allow me to split the Users into topics using a round-robin approach. There is very little information about how GlobalKTables work, though.

From [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-99%3A+Add+Global+Tables+to+Kafka+Streams#KIP-99:AddGlobalTablestoKafkaStreams-Compatibility,Deprecation,andMigrationPlan):

> Data arriving in the GlobalKTable will not trigger the join.

Is this true? And if it is true, how can I design this join to do what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Data arriving in the GlobalKTable will not trigger the join.

Yes, this holds.

> If the ClientConfiguration gets updated I need to re-process that configuration for each User.

If this implies, that you want to `seekToBeginning()` of the `userTopic` and re-reading this data, then you cannot use the joins from Kafka Streams for this.

---

Some material on the web about joins:

- https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-globalktable-join
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-globalktable-join
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

Answer (score 1):

> If the ClientConfiguration gets updated I need to re-process that configuration for each User.

My current understanding of GlobalKTable is that the only way to achieve such a behaviour is to simply (?) send each User again to the `userTopic`.

That'd be exactly what Kafka Streams would do anyway, so rather than Kafka Streams it's your job.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I came to the same conclusion, and have since done some redesigning things.